# How to create a new Dataframe column from an existing string column using split() method?

Tags: python, pandas, string, dataframe, series

I have a dataframe column with data like this:

```
| column_1 | 
| -------- | 
| 1:3      | 
| 1:4      |
| 1:6      |
| 5:6      |
```

I want to split this column into to two colums like this:

```
| column_1 | left_split     | right_split |
| -------- | -------------- | -------------- |
| 1:3      | 1              | 3              |
| 1:4      | 1              | 4              |
| 1:6      | 1              | 6              |
| 5:6      | 5              | 6              |
```

Now I have tried using this code:

```
df['left_split'] = df['column_1'].split(':')[0]
df['right_split'] = df['column_1'].split(':')[1]
```

and this code:

```
df['left_split'] = df['column_1'].lsplit(':')
df['right_split'] = df['column_1'].rsplit(':')
```

and also this:

```
df['left_split'] = df['column_1'].strip(':')[0]
df['right_split'] = df['column_1'].strip(':')[1]
```

However, these codes returns an attribute error "'Series' object has no attribute 'split'"

I am confused since when I type this:

```
df['column_1'].iloc[1].split(':')[0]
```

it works and displays the left sided number but when I remove the iloc (to apply it on all the column) and assign it to a new column, it does not work.

Would appreciate your help on this

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `expand=True` parameter in split, like this:

```
df[['left_split', 'right_split']] = df['column_1'].str.split(':', expand=True)
```

Full example:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame( {'column_1': {1: '1:3', 2: '1:4', 3: '1:6', 4: '5:6'}})
df[['left_split', 'right_split']] = df['column_1'].str.split(':', expand=True)

print(df)
#   column_1 left_split right_split
# 1      1:3          1           3
# 2      1:4          1           4
# 3      1:6          1           6
# 4      5:6          5           6
```

Comment: That did not work for me but I used the same concept to turn the column I wanted to a dictionary of lists using the split the syntax you use(excluding the parameter expand)
then using a for loop to strip each element from each list into two seperate lists and then assigning each new lists back to the columns I wanted.

I hoped there would have been another way using less code but nonetheless I achieved what I wanted

Comment: It brought back a ValueError

Comment: I added the full example, just copy paste so you can see each step. As for your own code. It does not work because for example .strip() is a string method. Meaning you can only use it with strings, not the pandas.Series() to get the string representation of the pandas.Series you need to use: `.str` so in your code just add the str like this: `df['column_1'].str.split(':')[0]`